# while swiping left and right the text is missing in the calendar

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented [JZCalendarWeekView](https://github.com/zjfjack/JZCalendarWeekView) in our project. We are facing UI issues while swiping left and right, the appointments label text is missing for some events randomly. I'm using the below code to refresh calendar after getting response from backend:

```
self.calenderWeekview.setupCalendar(numOfDays: 1,setDate: self.selectedDate, allEvents: eventsByDate,scrollType: .pageScroll)
```